# less css variables with color name

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to create a few dynamics classes width Less css.

The idea is use in html this class:

```
.color-white{
   color: white !important;
}
```

I created this sintaxis in Less:

```
.change-color(@which; @color){
  .color-@{which}{
    color:@color !important;
  }
  .background-@{which}{
    background-color:@color !important;
  }
}
```

So, with this I want to take my idea :D

```
.change-color(@which: white; @color: white);
```

But, that is the problem, I have this:

```
.color-#ffffff{
  color:#fff!important
}
.background-#ffffff{
  background-color:#fff!important
}
```

How can I use "white" as string and not as hex color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call this way instead:

`.change-color(@which: ~'white'; @color: ~'white');`

Though I think it would be better to just create a class called `.color-red` explicitly rather than make things more unreadable for little reason.